# Can a Fast Computer and Low CPU Usage Still Take Forever to Execute?

Tags: python, memory, nltk

I've got a very nice machine to play with over at Azure.  It's got 16 cores and memory up the wazoo.

Running on it is an app I wrote that does a LOT of crunching.  Basically dividing up about 100,000 text documents into ngrams and creating a document index.

I recently moved this app over from a pretty small AWS instance with about 1/20th of the processing power.  I couldn't even do 40,000 records without running out of memory.  It took about 30 minutes to index 30,000 records.

So now, even with all that processing power, I'm still sitting here waiting 30 minutes to crunch 30,000 records.  Is it just the nature of this type of process?  Or am I not really taking advantage of my resources properly?

**EDIT (THE CODE EXPLANATION):**
The part of the app taking the most time is looping through NLTK library looking for named entities within the text of each document.  I am running a loop of the 100k documents through a process very similar to this example:

https://gist.github.com/onyxfish/322906

Some stats:
Windows Azure VM
Python 2.7 (32 bit)  (Enthought Canopy Environment)
Numpy 1.7.0

Stats:[image]

Comment: Voting to close as unclear.  You haven't shown code, or described an algorithm, or anything like that, so the only answers can be "yes, it's possible you've written very inefficient code", or "yes, it's possible your problem requires a lot of memory", which isn't going to be much help.

Comment: I/O is a trivial additional explanation for this, especially if you're moving files/data around over the network

Answer (score 2):

If your process takes 0.3% of CPU time and takes a long time to execute, it clearly isn't CPU-bound.

If I had to guess based on the limited information provided, I'd guess that the code is I/O-bound. Write a little program that simply reads the 100,000 files and time it in the exact same execution environment. If that too is slow, you might want to consider merging the many files into few; it should improve things considerably.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I've edited the post to reflect that the bulk of the time spent running the script is in an entity extraction process using NLTK.